# Remove names from named vector and get only the values

Tags: r, vector, flatten

I have a vector like below

```
tmp <- c(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

> a b c
>   1 2 3

I want to flatten this vector to get only `1, 2, 3`.

I tried `unlist(tmp)` but it still gives me the same result.

How to achieve that efficiently?

Comment: Try `as.numeric(tmp)`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You just want to remove the `names` attribute from `tmp`.  There are a number of ways to do that.

You can `unname` it.

```
unname(tmp)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Or use a very common method for removing names, by setting them to `NULL`.

```
names(tmp) <- NULL
```

Or strip the attributes with `as.vector`.

```
as.vector(tmp)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Or re-concatenate it without the names.

```
c(tmp, use.names=FALSE)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Or use `setNames`.

```
setNames(tmp, NULL)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a use case that the above does not cover:

```
tmp <- c(1,2,3)
names(tmp) <- c("a","b","c")
```

In this case you need to use both:

```
unlist(unname(tmp))
```